# Let $A$ an integral domain. Show that the zero ring has only one associate: himself.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

I did the following demonstration: Would it be possible to give me a feedbak if i'm to wrong.

$A$  must be the zero ring.

Here's a proof.

By definition, if $a$ and $b$ are associates then each is a unit multiple of the other. In particular for this special $a$ we have that $b$ can be anything. Take $b=0$. Then $a=cb=0$ for some unit $c$, hence $a=0$. This uses the fact that $a$ is a multiple of $b$.

To finish the proof that $A$ is the zero ring, note that no matter what $b$ we choose, it must be a multiple of $a$. But $a=0$, hence $b=0$, so $0$ is the only element of $A$.

$\square$

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right ideas, but your presentation is a little bit disorganized. You're also a little bit confused about what you're trying to prove; you want to show that if $A$ in an integral domain, then $0$ has only itself as an associate. There's lots of ways to word something like this, but here is what I would write.

Suppose $A$ is an integral domain and let $r$ be an associate of $0$. If $A$ is the zero ring then the statement is obviously true. Suppose $A \neq 0$. Then there exists some unit $u$ such that $0 = ur$. Since $A$ is an integral domain this implies that $u =0$ or $r=0$ and since units are nonzero (here we are using that $A \neq 0$ implicitly), we have that $r=0$. Thus the only associate of $0$ is $0$, which was the desired result.

Note that your demonstration shows that any associate of $0$ must be $0$, not that every element in the ring is $0$ because you started by assuming that $a$ and $b$ are associates. This is an important distinction and one you should make sure you understand well.